# Camunda UI - Tasklist slider overlaps tasks in new Chrome/Edge versions

Tags: google-chrome, camunda, bpmn

My chrome browser recently upgraded to the latest version v104.0.5112.81 and the camunda tasklist slider now overlaps the display of the task form.

However it is fine on firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround , add to : `\server\apache-tomcat-9.0.33\webapps\camunda\app\tasklist\styles/user-styles.css` :

workaround for third column issue on chrome that excludes firefox

```
*/
@supports (-webkit-appearance:none) and (not (overflow:-webkit-marquee))
and (not (-ms-ime-align:auto)) and (not (-moz-appearance:none)) {
  @media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    .three-cols-layout-columns .column-right {
      z-index: 1;
      left: 800px;
      margin-left: auto ;
    }
  }

  [cam-tasklist-task] h2 {
    margin-top: 15px !important;
  }
  @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .three-cols-layout-columns .column-right {
      z-index: 1;
      left: 660px;
      margin-left: auto ;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (adjusting the middle column):

```css
@supports (-webkit-appearance:none) and (not (overflow:-webkit-marquee))
and (not (-ms-ime-align:auto)) and (not (-moz-appearance:none)) {
  @media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    .three-cols-layout-columns .column-center {
      margin-right: -360px;
    }
  }
  @media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
    .three-cols-layout-columns .column-center {
      margin-right: -320px;
    }
  }
  @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .three-cols-layout-columns .column-center {
      margin-right: -300px;
    }
  }
}
```